# how to run a r script in hive

Tags: r, hive

I have two tables in hive: one is test and another is train. I wrote some R code to fetch the tables from hive.

Here is the R code:

```
#loading library
library(RHive)

library(rhdfs)

library(rmr2)

library(gplots)

library(gtable)

library(gtools)

library(caTools)

library(RMySQL)

library(devtools)

rhive.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xxx",port=xxxxx, hiveServer2=FALSE, defaultFS=NULL,
              updateJar=FALSE, user=NULL, password=NULL)


train<-rhive.query("select * from train")
test<-rhive.query("select * from test")
trainglm <- glm(leadconverted~.,data=train)
p1<-predict.glm(trainglm,newdata=test,type="response") 
lcp<-as.matrix(p1[])
colnames(lcp)<-"LeadConverted"
test1<-cbind(test,lcp)

test2<-test1
colnames(test2)<-NULL
write.csv(test2,file="/home/dsri/Downloads/test1",quote=F,row.names=F)
rhive.query("drop table test")
rhive.query("CREATE TABLE test(Std_DistanctToVendor float,Std_Income float,Std_ZipPopulationDensity float,FirstLastPropCase INT,NameEmailCheck INT,SingleWeekday STRING,lead_TimeFrameCont STRING,
            ,Vehicle_FinanceMethod STRING,AddressProvided INT,Hybrid INT,LeadConverted float)
            ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE")
rhive.query("LOAD DATA local INPATH '/home/dsri/Downloads/test1' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test")
```

I saved this R code as `/home/dsri/Downloads/myscript.r`

I have to run this code from hive.

I am not getting how to start and how to proceed.

Comment: So what is your actual problem?  You haven't provided an error of any sort, just several function calls.  If you update your question to your specific problem then you will be more likely to find help.

Comment: My problem is that I have to run this Rscript in hive. I need help how to run this script from hive.

Comment: while running this in R I am not getting any error I have to run this from hive. I tried to run it from python I am getting the results.

Comment: But I want to know that can I run it from hive. like how I did in python.

Comment: import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call("/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla -e 'source(\"/home/dsri/Desktop/jayshree/hivecode.R\")'", shell=True)

Comment: Can you try `Rscript --vanilla -e hivecode.R` as your python shows?  What happens then?

Comment: It is working but, that is in python . I want to run the hivecode.R from hive.

Comment: I got something useful for my question... To run R script from command line we used to do:Rscript /path to the script/hivecode.R ; same thing we can do from hive command shell also we just have to add ! before the command..